# Alternative of PHP functions structure

Tags: php, function

Any alternative of end for PHP functions instead } ?
Something like

```
function test():
endfunction;
```

I saw alternative structures for if, while, switch or foreach, but nothing for functions.

Thank you!

Comment: why would you? You call the function and that's that, it's not like your closing off a function when you call it

Comment: Why would you want this? The alternative structures for control structures are intended for templating. Doing it for functions doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, there're __no__ alternatives.

Comment: @Xatenev It's unclear what they're asking because it makes little sense to want this functionality. The *why* is missing and highly important. I have little intention of quitting PHP, thanks.

Comment: @ceejayoz No the `why` doesn't matter here. We don't even have to care about why OP wants to do this - it might be just to gain additional knowledge without even having a real-world problem at all.

Comment: The why of it *does* matter, as it might allow us to steer OP in the right direction to solving the problem that led them to ask the question in a more suitable manner.

Comment: For anybody else still wondering why. I just needed a recursive function to display my category tree when I don't know how deep it is. So I wrote a function in my template.

Comment: I also use functions to create "templatelets" in PHP that I can use to insert a parametrized snippet of HTML into the output stream. endfunction would be useful for me, too. Currently, I use comments to delimit the HTML core of those templatelets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No this is not possible see http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures;
>   namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic
>   form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon
>   (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;,
>   or endswitch;, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell for sure but I think the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) was introduced to help the template designers identify easier where a control structure ends in the template files, where PHP code (mostly control structures) are mixed with HTML and Javascript (that also uses curly braces for its blocks).

This purpose excludes the functions from such a syntax. The template files are not an appropriate place to define functions.